# psycopg2 executemany not working

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

If I run

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_column = %s;', ('some_value',))
```

then a call to `cur.fetchall()` immediately afterwards succeeds, and produces an output that is entirely consistent with the result I get if I run the following in `psql`:

```
some_db=> SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_column = 'some_value';
```

But if I run

```
cur.executemany('SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_column = %s;',
                [('some_value',)])
```

...which should be basically equivalent to the `cur.execute(...)` statement before, the subsequent call to `cur.fetchall()` **raises an exception**:

```
ProgrammingError: no results to fetch
```

I get the same exception if the sequence passed as second argument in the call to `executemany` has multiple entries:

```
cur.executemany('SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_column = %s;',
                [('some_value',), ('some_other_value',)])
```

...or if I use the `pyformat` style for passing parameters

```
cur.executemany('SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_column = %(v)s;',
                [{'v': 'some_value'}, {'v': 'some_other_value'}])
```

What's wrong with my code?

BTW, I'm aware of this [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19154324/559827), but the answers there do not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`executemany` specifically discards any result sets that may be returned, so that is why you are getting the exception.

More info:
http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.executemany